# heroku "stack level too deep" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I have a problem to launch my app on heroku i get this error

```
heroku rake db:migrate --trace
(in /app)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:231
```

What should i look into in order to investigate about the problem?
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: do you overwrite system methods?

Comment: I have the exact same problem here, and the only thing I've done is installed Devise. Then "rake db:migrate" gives this error. Should I split migration to pieces maybe?

Comment: One more thing: from shell I added "ulimit -s unlimited" then checked with "ulimit -a" and I can see my stack is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the migration works (e.g. on your computer)
2. Run `heroku logs` and take a look at what the logs say